# Get this error message, when creating foreign key (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, cascade, create-table

I try to create the table "gallery" with a foreign key on the "users" table. 
The table "users" I have already created. If I want to create the "Gallery "table, I always get this error message.

users:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

gallery:

```
CREATE TABLE gallery (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT gallery_fk1
INDEX username (username),
FOREIGN KEY (username)
    REFERENCES users(username)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

error message:

```
#1005 - Can't create table `gallery`.`gallery` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: First make sure your `users` table actually exists, because `PRIMARY KEY (building_no)` is not a valid primary key. Then you would have to add an index on `username` in the `users` table. But you actually shouldn't do that. The correct use of foreign keys and normalization would be to use the `userid` instead of `username` in `gallery` and refer to the `id` in `users` (which should be the primary key).

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake. With the id as fk it works.